# How to print a vertical bar in text mode without the use of the "|" symbol?

Tags: symbols, characters

I'm trying to print the vertical bar symbol in text mode, but I can't use the `|` symbol itself. What is the right command for this? Please, don't suggest to use `\rule`, since I need the standard symbol in the current font.

Comment: Curiosity: your keyboard doesn't have the key `|`?

Comment: Or when you type `|`, it renders as `-`?  Why can't you use the `|` symbol itself?

Comment: Yes, the keyboard is broken :)

Comment: `\textbar` right?

Comment: @mbert if you make it an answer, I will gladly accept it

Comment: Note: [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) correctly identifies `\textbar`.

Comment: If the keyboard is broken, or simply lacks the key in your layout, pasting the symbol can be the simplest solution, rather than resorting to cluttering up the code with unexpected macros.  In this case though, we have a suitably-named text-mode symbol so it's not too bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command to produce a `|` is `\textbar`. See `lttextcomp.dtx` in [`source2e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf). Note this works even in `OT1` encoding, where `|` produces a horizontal bar